# Create a histogram based on one row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         A      B       C       D       E       F       G     H    
 0     309     38     378    1422    1250     938     736    11
```

I want to use either matplotlib or seaborn to create a histogram where each bar represents a df column (`A`, `B`, `C`, etc.), and the height of each column is the value in the 0th index(only row in the df).

Comment: Did you try looking for some solution on SO?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want a bar chart... Not a histogram

```
df.T[0].plot.bar()
# df.loc[0].plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: What about if I want to have stacked bars, for example: A, B, and C should be stacked with different colors and E, G, and H need to be stacked with different colors? I know how to do it in R, but having trouble in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = df.iloc[0].to_dict()
names = list(data.keys())
values = list(data.values())

y_pos = np.arange(len(names))
plt.bar(y_pos,values, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, names)
plt.ylabel('Usage')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! What about if I want to have stacked bars, for example: A, B, and C should be stacked with different colors and E, G, and H need to be stacked with different colors?